# Machine Learning Library OpenCV 2.1

Tags: qt, opencv, machine-learning

I've tried to compile the [CvEM example](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/ml_expectation-maximization.html?highlight=em#CvEM%3a%3atrain) of the documentation. I've set the library search path to opencv\lib and also the include path. I've included the -lml machine learning library however I reveive the following error:

> undefined reference to `CvEM::CvEM()`

If I comment `CvEM em_model` the code compiles:

```
// CvEM em_model;
CvEMParams params;
```

CvEMParams doesn't result in an error, so I think that the include paths are ok. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

If I run the code in Visual Studio, it runs perfectly.

EDIT: Added other information

My .pro file has the following commands

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV2.1/include

INCLUDEPATH += C:/OpenCV2.1/include/opencv

LIBS += -L"C:/OpenCV2.1/bin" -lcv210 -lcxcore210 -lcvaux210 -lhighgui210 -lml210 -lcxts210 \-lnetapi32`
```

And my compilation looks like this :

```
Running build steps for project Check...
Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
Starting: "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe"
C:/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Documents and Settings/Bush/Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug'
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o debug\Check.exe debug/main.o debug/mainwindow.o debug/moc_mainwindow.o  -L"c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.4\mingw\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -LC:/OpenCV2.1/bin -lcv210 -lcxcore210 -lcvaux210 -lhighgui210 -lml210 -lcxts210 -lnetapi32 -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4 -LC:\OpenSSL-Win32_full\lib 
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Documents and Settings/Bush/Check-build-desktop-    Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug'
debug/mainwindow.o: In function `MainWindow':
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:23: undefined reference to `CvEM::CvEM()'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:49: undefined reference to `CvEM::train(CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvEMParams, CvMat*)'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:59: undefined reference to `CvEM::predict(CvMat const*, CvMat*) const'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:76: undefined reference to `CvEM::~CvEM()'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:76: undefined reference to `CvEM::~CvEM()'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:23: undefined reference to `CvEM::CvEM()'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:49: undefined reference to `CvEM::train(CvMat const*, CvMat const*, CvEMParams, CvMat*)'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:59: undefined reference to `CvEM::predict(CvMat const*, CvMat*) const'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:76: undefined reference to `CvEM::~CvEM()'
C:\Documents and Settings\Bush\Check-build-desktop-Qt_4_7_4_for_Desktop_-_MinGW_4_4__Qt_SDK__Debug/../Check/mainwindow.cpp:76: undefined reference to `CvEM::~CvEM()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\Check.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
The process "C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building project Check (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using? What is the full command you are using to compile? Also, the link you've provided is broken, can you double check it please.

Comment: Thank you Chris, I ve updated my post. I look forward to hearing from you.

Answer (score 0):

Just recompile the distribution with qt's version of mingw and it will work.